# pandas binning via cut including single value (zero) bin

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas in Python, given

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.0])
```

how to do binning where the first bin only contains zeros?

Tried

```
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 0), (0, 0.1), (0.1, 0.2), (0.2, float("inf"))])
pd.cut(s, bins)
```

which gives

```
0           NaN
1    (0.0, 0.1]
2    (0.1, 0.2]
3    (0.2, inf]
4           NaN
5    (0.1, 0.2]
6    (0.0, 0.1]
7    (0.2, inf]
8           NaN
dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(0.0, 0.0] < (0.0, 0.1] < (0.1, 0.2] < (0.2, inf]]
```

but

```
zero_bin = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 0)], closed="both")
pd.cut(s, zero_bin)
```

results in

```
0    [0.0, 0.0]
1           NaN
2           NaN
3           NaN
4    [0.0, 0.0]
5           NaN
6           NaN
7           NaN
8    [0.0, 0.0]
dtype: category
Categories (1, interval[int64]): [[0, 0]]
```

But I did not find a way to combine the `zero_bin` and `bins` to get the desired result of

```
0    [0.0, 0.0]
1    (0.0, 0.1]
2    (0.1, 0.2]
3    (0.2, inf]
4    [0.0, 0.0]
5    (0.1, 0.2]
6    (0.0, 0.1]
7    (0.2, inf]
8    [0.0, 0.0]
dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [[0.0, 0.0] < (0.0, 0.1] < (0.1, 0.2] < (0.2, inf]]
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I also want to bin where the first bin only contains zeros

Comment: @Jiren no, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but to anyone with this doubt, you should use the argument `include_lowest=True` inside pd.cut

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The output is the same as above, even with `include_lowest=True` so I don't see how this helps?